# Convert Base64 image from Landscape to Portrait

Tags: base64, mule, mule-studio, mulesoft

In Mule4 I have image/png base64 data returned from an API call. When I decode the data I can see the image. However the image is coming out as landscape. Please can someone advise how I can convert this to portrait inside Mule? Is there something I need to change in the base64 data itself or can I perhaps write a java code snippet that could do this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DataWeave [fromBase64()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-binaries-functions-frombase64) function to decode the data and then use Java code to perform the transformation. Mule doesn't provide any image manipulation features, which makes sense.

I would recommend to encapsulate the transformation in a [Mule module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/getting-started) using the Mule SDK, for easy reuse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately all the Java code I could find had to do with rotating or flipping the image, which is not what I am after. When the image is rotated is just places the text sideways. I need the text to still be upright but with a portrait orientation. Could you perhaps point me to java code that changes the orientation of an image? Cheers

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do that for simple image formats, as the text is just more pixels in it. If the file format allows separate layers or objects for texts it could be possible, but you will need a specific library and code for it. I suggest to update the question will more details of what you just mentioned and the file format.